# Integrate ruby application within rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, api, websocket

Im in the need of integrating a cramp ( web sockets based chat app ) with an existing rails app.

What are the steps to integrate ruby app with views to rails app? move all views to the rails app then write an api to communicate with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your app is a Rack app you can just [mount it](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Base.html#method-i-mount) in your routes file.

See [this Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/222-rack-in-rails-3) for a practical example.

I've [had some trouble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9533830/sinatra-rack-middleware-hijacks-root-url) sharing views through Rack, so you may want to see if you can write it in to a Rails Engine which gives you more access to the containing Rails app.